# Highcharts :Uncaught TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, highcharts

Getting this error while running a HighCharts in my JSP Application.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function(anonymous function) @ VendorReports:125n.Callbacks.j @ jquery-1.11.0.js:893n.Callbacks.k.fireWith @ jquery-1.11.0.js:928n.extend.ready @ jquery-1.11.0.js:982K @ jquery-1.11.0.js:989
```

Please suggest what to do

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        colors: ["#7cb5ec", "#f7a35c"],
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumtion, grouped by gender'
        },
        xAxis: {
           categories: ['Apples' ]
        },
        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Number of fruits'
            }
            //Nothing wrong with this code
```

Comment: can you please add jsfiddle?

Comment: Can't reproduce, it works swimmingly -> **http://jsfiddle.net/nate439j/**

Comment: @Farhan, http://jsfiddle.net/mxex28e2/. Its working there, But when put the same in my JSP, getting this error

Comment: Then something is wrong with your JSP, not the above code

Comment: Yes @adeneo, I practiced there & copied to my page. here not working

Comment: check you libraries are they included in proper hierarchy. jquery library must be included first, also check your jquery version match it with demo

Comment: @Farhan, I added 1st jquery, then highcharts followed by exporting.js .. Please check above

Comment: My friend I am asking to check in your code :). as you said demo is working perfect then some js libraries or code is creating error

Comment: Checked Friend.. :( :(

Comment: Check the network tab in your console to see if the resources are all being loaded properly. You might have a path wrong or something.

Comment: also you can check by removing extra code which is not relevant of this specific code step by step. That might also be help you. I hope

Comment: How about setting "target" on files to load them in header ?

Comment: Saw same issue. I was loading jquery after Highchart which caused the issue. Changed order and it's working now.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I was having this issue, too. Ensure jQuery is imported before highchart.js. That fixed the issue for me.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

Comment: Same here, I just realized that highcharts is a library which depends on jQuery and so jQuery has to go on top of the highcharts.

Just make this change and anyone should be good to go.! So naive mistaken - how can I do that.! :)

Answer (score 38):

What happens if you replace

```
$('#container').highcharts({
        colors: ["#7cb5ec", "#f7a35c"],
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        /* ... */
```

by

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                colors: ["#7cb5ec", "#f7a35c"],
                chart: {
                    type: 'column',
                    renderTo: 'container'
                },
                /* ... */
```

?

I had the same issue as you a while ago and I resolved it by using this type of initialization.

Comment: But how to call the chart to attach to the container?

Comment: Look at the line `renderTo: 'container'`. It's where your define to which html element you attach the chart: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.renderTo

Comment: It looks its working but graph is not displayed :(.. No error

Comment: Then your series may have a problem. How do you initialize your data ? Paste a sample of your array for example.

Comment: But I want to render it to existing element.. Is it possible? If i render to new element, It is drawn at the end of page

Comment: You can render it to the element that you want, just by specifying the id of the element in the `renderTo` attribute. The position will depend on the CSS associated.

Comment: Thank you very much... You saved me :) :)

Answer (score 2):

I was using an old version of the high charts version.  From their website I assumed that the version listed under Specific version was their latest version and used that so it wouldn't auto update on me.  However the version they had listed was super old so changing it to the actual latest version fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The approach taken from the official examples is working well. They defined the include script tag within the body tag therefore the solution given by Kabulan0lak is better I think.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Highcharts Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'spline'
                }
                // ... other options and data/series
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens with me too. In my case, I need click in a button to load the chart and if I click twice or more the chart stops to work. I was setting the color like this:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
        colors: Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function (color) {
            return {
                radialGradient: {
                    cx: 0.5,
                    cy: 0.3,
                    r: 0.7
                },
                stops: [
                    [0, color],
                    [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
                ]
            };
        })
    });

$.getJSON("./myDataGraph.php", function(response){
        // Create the chart
        var chart = Highcharts.chart('myGraph', {
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false,
                type: 'pie'
            },
... });
```

I couldn't solve the error, but I remove the "Highcharts.setOptions" and the chart works!!!